# Изменение цвета arrow, в зависимости от слайда

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как менять цвет стрелок, листающих слайды, в зависимости от цвета в боковых слайдах?

Comment: что бы тебе помогли, советую выложить сюда код, что именно у тебя  наработано и что не получается...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Возможно, вам стоит посмотреть в сторону:
[prev()](https://jquery-docs.ru/prev/)
[closest()](https://jquery-docs.ru/closest/)

Answer (score -1):

Наверное, один из самых простых вариантов - это менять цвет в определенном порядке по нажатию на кнопку, т.е. задавать стиль кнопке разный по нажатию.. Но это только если слайды идут в определенном порядке

Comment: а не лутше, цвет для стрелок слайдера получать из цвета фона `title` (из блока "CINEMA", ""TRAVEL). тогда не надо будет писать определенный порядок.